# Funny grep situation

Tags: xml, grep

I have 99999 XML-files which I presume all contain the tag `"<A_ItemKey>"`.

When I run this command:

```
cat *.xml | grep "<A_ItemKey>" | wc -l
```

I get the result 75140

However if I run this command:

```
grep "<A_ItemKey>" *.xml | wc -l
```

I get the result 99999 (which I believe is correct).

Why don't these two commands show the same results?

Many thanks in advance:-)

/Paul

Comment: If you concatenate files and some files do not have a trailing line feed you might get this result... :-?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the files don't end in a newline.

```
$ printf '<A_ItemKey>' > 1
$ printf '<A_ItemKey>' > 2
$ grep '<A_ItemKey>' 1 2
1:<A_ItemKey>
2:<A_ItemKey>
$ grep '<A_ItemKey>' 1 2 | wc -l
2
$ cat 1 2 | grep '<A_ItemKey>'
<A_ItemKey><A_ItemKey>
$ cat 1 2 | grep '<A_ItemKey>' | wc -l
1
```

BTW, using "grep" and "xml" in one sentence is, indeed, "funny".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Actually I was thinking there was an upper limit to the cat-command that it could not handle more than 75140 (or something) files:-) Your answers make sense.

Comment: However giving it some more consideration this can't be the reason for the situation. The tag "<A_ItemKey>" will never occur twice on the same line. The structure of the XML-files makes this impossible. There must be another reason.

Comment: Try running `grep -o` if your system supports it. It should output each match on a separate line.

Comment: That made the difference:-) "grep -o" gives 99999 in both commands. Díky moc!